# Android : Storing ExtendedProperties on Exchange Server

Tags: java, android, android-calendar, exchange-server-2007

i'm using `SyncAdapter` to store Extra data like `ExtendedProperties` on an android app calendar, it works fine when storing `ExtendedProperties` on local, my calendar app is syncing with Exchange server.

**Problem**

The facing issue, is that i cannot find those `ExtendedProperties` when i fetch them on Exchange Server.

Comment: Hi @Ethan, have your any idea my issue?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the `ExtendedProperties` fields are not synced like the other calendar fields. so they are not sent to the exchange server at all.